# Application folder not found

Tags: android, image

I'm trying to save one image on application folder to remove the image when user un-install the application, but when I try open application folder manually I can't see it.

Example : "data/data/MyApplicationFolder/"

Is there anyway to make the folder visible ?

Comment: As you uninstall the application your application folder will automatically gets deleted so all the data you have stored in application folder will also deleted.

Comment: My question is why i cant see the application folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application folder `data/data/` is not visible to user unless the device rooted

Answer (score 0):

As you uninstall the application your application folder will automatically gets deleted so all the data you have stored in application folder will also deleted.

If you want to check your application folder data then you must check it before uninstalling the application only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my question was not clear, but i found the answer

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath()  +"/Android/data/"+getPackageName()+"/files/");
```

i hop this help someone, thanks guys